# Trying to understand what's happening over key=lambda x: (count[x], -x)?

Tags: python, sorting, lambda

I am trying to understand what key=lambda x: (count[x], -x) meaning in this function.

```
def frequencySort(self, nums: List[int]) -> List[int]:
        count = collections.Counter(nums)
        return sorted(nums, key=lambda x: (count[x], -x))
```

Comment: The sort key is a tuple, `(count[x], -x)`. `count[x]` is the frquency of x. `-x` is the negated value for `x`. So this will sort the values first by their frequency. And if the frequencies are same then by their negative values - i.e reverse order == larger values come before smaller ones

Comment: The lambda means that it is anonymous function with x as it's argument

Comment: What parts of ``key=lambda x: (count[x], -x)`` *do* you understand?

Comment: Have you read the documentation on [`sorted()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The sort key is a tuple, `(count[x], -x)`. `count[x]` is the frequency of `x`. `-x` is the negated value for `x`. So this will sort the values first by their frequency, and if the frequencies are the same, then by their negative values - i.e reverse order == larger values come before smaller ones

*-- [comment](/questions/67605542/trying-to-understand-whats-happening-over-key-lambda-x-countx-x#comment119495766_67605542) by [rdas](/users/2947378/rdas) (with minor corrections)*